# User Based Recommendation in R

Tags: r, recommendation-engine, rscript

I am trying to do user based recommendation in R by using `recommenderlab` package but all the time I am getting 0(no) prediction out of the model.

my code is :

```
library("recommenderlab")        
# Loading to pre-computed affinity data  
movie_data<-read.csv("D:/course/Colaborative filtering/data/UUCF Assignment Spreadsheet_user_row.csv")


movie_data[is.na(movie_data)] <- 0

rownames(movie_data) <- movie_data$X
movie_data$X <- NULL

# Convert it as a matrix
R<-as.matrix(movie_data)
# Convert R into realRatingMatrix data structure
#   realRatingMatrix is a recommenderlab sparse-matrix like data-structure
r <- as(R, "realRatingMatrix")
r

rec=Recommender(r[1:nrow(r)],method="UBCF", param=list(normalize = "Z-score",method="Cosine",nn=5, minRating=1))

recom <- predict(rec, r["1648"], n=5)
recom
as(recom, "list")
```

all the time I am getting out put like :

```
as(recom, "list")
$`1648`
character(0)
```

I am using user-row data from this link:
https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BxANCLmMqAyIQ0ZWSy1KNUI4RWc/view
In that data column A contains user id and apart from that all are movie rating for each movie name.

Thanks.

Comment: How can I reproduce the `character(0)` result on my machine? I don't have "UUCF Assignment Spreadsheet_user_row.csv" and reading the google drive thingy somehow does not work (did you try it?)

Comment: Hi, @lukeA FYI please download data from https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1JHI_xYOPWnzfsVyUxLJ6CmO5pdE1WuuVZcEcwllnIBo/edit#gid=871073012

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The line of code `movie_data[is.na(movie_data)] <- 0` is the source of the error. For `realRatingMatrix` (unlike the `binaryRatingMatrix`) the movies that are *not rated* by the users are expected to be *NA* values, not zero values. For example, the following code gives the correct predictions:

```
library("recommenderlab")        
movie_data<-read.csv("UUCF Assignment Spreadsheet_user_row.csv")
rownames(movie_data) <- movie_data$X
movie_data$X <- NULL

R<-as.matrix(movie_data)
r <- as(R, "realRatingMatrix")    
rec=Recommender(r,method="UBCF", param=list(normalize = "Z-score",method="Cosine",nn=5, minRating=1))     
recom <- predict(rec, r["1648"], n=5)
as(recom, "list")
# [[1]]
# [1] "X13..Forrest.Gump..1994."    "X550..Fight.Club..1999."                                   
# [3] "X77..Memento..2000."         "X122..The.Lord.of.the.Rings..The.Return.of.the.King..2003."
# [5] "X1572..Die.Hard..With.a.Vengeance..1995."
```